# Does a Java enum itself extend an interface I can make use of?

Tags: java, enums

I have several enums which implement an interface I've defined.  Now I'd like to provide some boilerplate operations on these enums based on their common interface as well as their common enum ancestry.  Is this possible?

In other words, I have:

```
public enum Car implements Vehicle {
    FORD, HONDA;
}

public interface Vehicle {
    String getLicensePlate();
}
```

And I'd now like to write something like this, perhaps in a default interface method or some other common place:

```
public static showLicensePlates(Vehicle.class vEnum) {
  for(Vehicle v : vEnum.values()) {
    System.out.println(v.getLicensePlate());
  }
}
```

Notice how I'm relying on enum's "values()" method, so the interface must be an enum for this to work.  How can I specify that this interface must be an enum?  Or if that's not possible, how an I write boilerplate methods to operate on enums in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is for the `showLicensePlates()` method to only take an argument that is both a vehicle and enum.  This is done with generics:

```
public <T extends Enum & Vehicle> showLicensePlates(T vEnum) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't know that Java had an "intersection" type operator for generics, that's awesome!  Wonder if it also has a union operator?

Comment: To make it fully correct, you should use `<T extends Enum<T> & Vehicle>`.

Answer (score 1):

Can call

```
Vehicle.class.getEnumConstants()
```

If it does not return null,then its an enum.

Java doc says:
Returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object does not represent an enum type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the interface and the Enumerator implemets such... then you can adapt the enum to return some Ids and...

```
interface Vehicle {
    String getLicensePlate();
}
enum Car implements Vehicle {
    FORD("F-007"), HONDA("H-860");
    private final String id;

    private Car(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLicensePlate() {
    return this.id;
    }
}
```

...and play with the Constraints in the method **ShowLicenseMEthod**.

```
public class Abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Abc c = new Abc();
    c.showLicensePlates(Car.class);
    }

    public <E extends Enum<E> & Vehicle> void showLicensePlates(Class<E> vEnum) {
    for (E v : vEnum.getEnumConstants()) {
        System.out.println(v.getLicensePlate());
    }
    }

}
```

Then you can pass ALL the enum classes you have and the method will print the **LicensePlates** of all the Enum Constants...